# Infinite scroll based on mouse scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Want to implement infinite scroll based on mouse scrol when it reaches the specified container bottom. I came to this plugin after searching http://www.infinite-scroll.com/ which needs the following basic requirements:

```
// infinitescroll() is called on the element that surrounds 
// the items you will be loading more of
  $('#content').infinitescroll({

    navSelector  : "div.navigation",            
                   // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
    nextSelector : "div.navigation a:first",    
                   // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    itemSelector : "#content div.post"          
                   // selector for all items you'll retrieve
  });
```

i.e next and previous selectors. Can we have infinite scroll based on mouse scroll instead of clicking next, prev links i.e when mouse reaches the specified container bottom load the content via ajax

Comment: what is actually your question? You have already got http://www.infinite-scroll.com/ , and it does exactly what you want. Now what?

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find the demo + sample code to load content on mouse scroll. I don't want next, prev links to load more content.

Comment: @RockySingh just a guess, but maybe it wants the links just to know where to look for the next page of data. Maybe you could include those links but keep them hidden.

Comment: @RockySingh that page it self is a demo :P :D try scrolling down!

Comment: Can you give the sample for it?

Comment: See my answer, Only jQuery is needed. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37613960/3732187

Answer (score 0):

Add a function to the scroll event and check if you scrolled down to the bottom.
you have to adjust numbers and tweak the code a bit according to your layout:

```
var $window = $(window);

$(document).ready(function () {

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var scrollheight2;
            scrollheight2 = $window.scrollTop();

            if (($("#content").height() - scrollheight2) <= 100) {
                    //AJAX STUFF
            }
        });
    });
```