# Infinite scroll detecting bottom of page only if there is nothing underneath

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm doing an infinite scroll page with angularjs that loads more items when the user reaches the bottom of the page. My problem is that under the infinite scroll container may or may not have more "stuff". So i don't want to load more items if the user reaches the bottom of the page if that "stuff" is present. So i want to load more items when the infinite scroll container reaches the end of that container and not the end of the page.

For the infinite scroll i have an angularjs directive like this:

```
myApp.directive("scroll", function ($window) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
         angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function(event) {
             var docHeight = $(document).height();
             var reachBottom = $($window).scrollTop() == (docHeight - $($window).height());
             if (reachBottom) {
                  setTimeout(scope.loadMore(), 100);
             }
         });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get stuff height under infiniti scroll container and use it

```
 var docHeight = $(document).height();
 var stuffHeight = $('#stuff').height();
 var reachBottom = $($window).scrollTop() == (docHeight - ($($window).height() + stuffHeight));
 if (reachBottom) {
      setTimeout(scope.loadMore(), 100);
 }
```

Comment: My problem with this is that there's not a `$('#stuff')` element that i can handle to get the height

Comment: user scroll container height for find stuff height or just simply `if $($window).scrollTop() == $('#container').height()`

Answer (score 0):

Only using jQuery you can do it. See this code snippet below.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var w = $(window);
        loadNewPage();

        // Each time the user scrolls
        w.scroll(function () {
            // End of the document reached?
            if ($(document).height() - win.height() == win.scrollTop()){
                loadNewPage();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```